# Intermittent Error on ML Engine when training large data using custom code training

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I encountered intermittent problem when running custom code training job on Google ML Engine. The code is running Python TensorFlow segmentation task. It is intermittent because, when we run the same task for the second time, the job is successful.

This intermittent problem recurring many times (more than 30x). 
I have run the same custom code offline with the same data-set, they are so far not producing the same error.

> Below is the payload error:

```
jsonPayload: {
  created:  1563475627.0648582   
  levelname:  "CRITICAL"   
  lineno:  274
  message:  "Unexpected Event status: 1"
  pathname:  "tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc"
 }
```

The question is how do we troubleshoot this problem ?

**Update:** My initial test is this could be caused by newer version of tensorflow (1.12) in this case as the problem does not happen on the previous version (1.8). Both cases running on the GPU card Tesla K80 (compute profile 3.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot this issue, apparently you can increase TF logging level to be more verbose (and debug logging if necessary).

As well as, please check any error related to the graphics driver. Specifically, the issue is related to this [topic](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31917)

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this problem is by running the training code on the earlier ML-engine (earlier TensorFlow version) at 1.8.

Since then, we did not encounter similar problem.